# Use result of aggregate in same select?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4

Is it possible to feed the result of an aggregate select into the same select with Postgresql?

I'm aware of the `WITH` clause -- but, this would be true syntactical sugar, wouldn't it?

```
SELECT some_agg(x) as y, some_func(y) FROM z;
```

Is Postgres smart enough to run the aggregation once if it's written as:

```
SELECT some_agg(x), some_func( some_agg(x) ) FROM z;
```

Comment: I believe you would see that in the execution plan when using `explain analyze`

Answer (score 3):

As far as I'm aware (up to 9.2), you can not.  They may have implemented that change in 9.3 or 9.4 ... but typically you would use a CTE (WITH) or just the same aggregate function..

`SELECT some_agg(x) as y, some_func(some_agg(x)) from z;`

I seem to recall that postgres is smart enough to know that it can reuse the `some_agg(x)` without having to calculate it twice.

*EDIT* - Adding a CTE example

```
WITH my_cte AS (
  SELECT
    id,
    some_agg(x) as y
  FROM tab
  GROUP BY id
) SELECT
  id, y, some_func(y)
FROM my_cte;
```

The easiest way to know for sure if it calculates it more than once would be to run an EXPLAIN on the plan and see.  :)

I entered the following SQL on a local DB that I have.. Below is the SQL and Explain Plan.

```
explain analyze
select
  product, sum(price) as x, sum(price) as y
from ticketlines
group by product
having sum(price) > 300;
```

You can see I have the same aggregate used 3 times ... here is the explain output:

```
HashAggregate  (cost=796.36..796.97 rows=49 width=16) (actual time=4.650..4.658 rows=26 loops=1)
  Filter: (sum(price) > 300::double precision)
  Rows Removed by Filter: 24
  ->  Seq Scan on ticketlines  (cost=0.00..692.68 rows=10368 width=16) (actual time=0.006..1.020 rows=10368 loops=1)
Total runtime: 4.699 ms
```

It only calculates the aggregate once.

Comment: Thx -- that is precisely my concern, is PG running the aggregation twice.

Comment: As long as the `some_agg(x)` is EXACTLY the same (including input parameters), I believe that's correct. Let me try to find a citation..  Just to be clear, though - either way, a Common Table Expression (CTE) will do what you need, it sounds like.

Comment: I am having trouble finding documentation about that specific behavior in the Postgres Documentation ... but I just did a simple `explain analyze` to see .. the results confirm what I said.